# Is Integration Greater than the Function We are Integrating?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, proof-explanation, solution-verification

On p. 461  of the Sixth Edition of Hardy and Wright's *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers* (Theorem 423). [(see this post)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3860492/which-book-has-the-proof-of-sum-n-leq-x-logh-frac-x-n-ox) it is written that -
$$ \int_{n-1}^{n}\log^h{(\frac x t)}dt \geq \log^h{(\frac x n)} $$

**My Understanding:** We see that $\int_{n-1}^{n}f(x)\,dx$ is accumulating/summing/integrating all points from $n-1$ to $n$  for function $f$ whereas $\int_{n-1}^{n}f(n)\,dx = f(n)$ is just holding the value of $n$ for function $f$, ***thus it is always true that*** $$f(n)\leq \int_{n-1}^{n} f(t)dt $$

Is it correct?

**Confusion:**  I have been told that it's generally true if $f$ is *decreasing* (and integrable), which $t\mapsto \log^h(x/t)$ is. If $f$ is decreasing, then $\int_{n-1}^n f(t)\textrm{d}t\geq \int_{n-1}^n f(n)\textrm{d}t=f(n).$ If $f$ is increasing, then $f(x) \le f(n)$ for all $x \in [n-1,n]$ Hence,$\int_{n-1}^{n}f(x)\,dx \le \int_{n-1}^{n}f(n)\,dx = f(n)$, but how does increasing or decreasing matter ? The function is given for a point and integration is done in between an interval.

Please clear my confusion in detail,  in general,

How can I prove rigorously that -

$$f(n)\leq \int_{n-1}^{n} f(t)dt ?$$

what are the necessary conditions?

Comment: This is obviously false. If $x=n$, the the LHS is zero while the RHS is $n^{1+Re(s)}$. It is true though that the integral is at least $(x-n)n^{1+Re(s)}$.

Comment: @amsmath  I have attached the source.

Comment: The (true) inequality in your reference is different to the one you posted.

Comment: @amsmath what I wrote is  implied by that inequality, is it ok?

Comment: "what I wrote is implied by that inequality" No, it isn't.

Comment: @amsmath  if we  invert both sides of the inequality  then the direction/sign of the inequality changes

Comment: Is $(1+2)^{-1} = 1^{-1} + 2^{-1}$?

Comment: @amsmath  no, could u plz clarify my mistake in detail brother?

Comment: Are we brothers? Huh, that's new to me... Dude, an integral is kind of a sum. if you invert both sides, then the LHS becomes $(\int\dots\,dt)^{-1}$. This is of course not the same as $\int(\dots)^{-1}\,dt$.

Comment: @amsmath  removed that part bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just explain what they did there. Bro... Let $a = Re(s) > 0$. Then $\frac 1{t^{1+a}}$ is decreasing on $[n,n+1]$. So, $\frac 1{t^{1+a}}\le\frac 1{n^{1+a}}$ for $t\in [n,n+1]$. Thus, $\int_n^x\frac 1{t^{1+a}}\,dt\le\int_n^x\frac 1{n^{1+a}}\,dt$. Now, the integrand on the RHS is a constant, so you can pull it out of the interal: $$\int_n^x\frac 1{t^{1+a}}\,dt\le\int_n^x\frac 1{n^{1+a}}\,dt = \frac 1{n^{1+a}}\int_n^x\,1\,dt = \frac 1{n^{1+a}}(x-n)\le \frac 1{n^{1+a}},$$because $x-n\le 1$.

Answer (score 1):

It is true in general that:
$$
\int_a^b f(x)dx \ge \inf_{x\in(a,b)}(f(x))\cdot (b-a)
$$
$\inf_{x\in(a,b)}(f(x))$ is basically the minimum value of $f(x)$ for $x\in(a,b)$, if you are unfamiliar with infimum.

For example, if $f$ is decreasing, then $f(x)\ge f(b)$ for all $x<b$. Then:
$$
\int_a^b f(x)dx \ge \int_a^b f(b)dx = f(b)\cdot(b-a)
$$

If f is increasing, then $f(x)\le f(b)$ for all $x<b$. Then:
$$
\int_a^b f(x)dx \le \int_a^b f(b)dx = f(b)\cdot(b-a)
$$

Think about the integral as the area under $f$. Changing $f(x)$ to the constant $f(b)$ means that we find the area of the rectangle with base $(b-a)$ and height $f(b)$. Depending on wether $f$ is increasing or decreasing, that rectangle will have greater or smaller area the the graph of $f$.

Comment: and $f(n)\leq \int_{n-1}^{n} f(t)dt $ is proved ? could u please include the finishing ?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit.

Comment: @Andrew You can just set $a=n-1$, $b=n$ now.