# Which book has the proof of $\sum_{n \leq x}\log^h(\frac x n)= O(x)$?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

I am looking for books that contains the proof of $\sum_{n \leq x}\log^h(\frac x n)= O(x)$.

**EDITED QUESTION**

I have the proof (in a lecture sheet), looking for a book for the reference.

According to one answer, the proof appears on p. 461 ff of the Sixth Edition of Hardy and Wright's *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers* (Theorem 423).

But it looks like that is not the book I am looking for.

Is there any other book that contains the proof?

I have checked Tom M Apostol's Book.

Comment: What is $\log^h$? Is it iterated (natural) logarithm or the $h$th power of the (natural) logarithm?

Comment: @JackLeGrüß yes bro it is  $h^{th}$ power of the (natural) logarithm

Comment: So are you looking for a specific/any book containing such a proof or you’re also looking for a proof (here)?

Comment: @JackLeGrüß I have the proof (in a lecture sheet), looking for the book.

Comment: “The” book sounds very specific; so unless you can give a snapshot of the proof for someone to recognize which “particular” book, I’m afraid you might not get the help you need. (Unless, otherwise, you’re hoping for any reference text containing a proof).

Comment: @JackLeGrüß ohh.. sorry mate, it could be any book ...grammatical mistake :)

Comment: It seems quite easy, for any fixed h, f(2x) < 2f(x) + log^h(2x). You might find it as an exercise with solution, but probably not as a theorem.

Comment: What is $f$ that you mean?

Answer (score 2):

The proof appears on p. 461 ff of the Sixth Edition of Hardy and Wright's *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers* (Theorem 423).

Comment: DID you know that before redeing this question or you found out? If  there is a way search, please share.

Comment: I didn't know the theorem beforehand. I read your post yesterday. Today, while browsing through the appropriate chapter in Hardy and Wright, I came across the result and recognized it. So, no search involved. Just a coincidence.